# What is the format of raw geometry column in PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, geometry

It doesn't seem to be a WKB, since it's basically a string, so what is it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the hexadecimal rendition (two characters per byte) of the EWKB format.

Per [the documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.0/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#EWKB_EWKT):

> The "canonical forms" of a PostgreSQL type are the representations you get with a simple query (without any function call) and the one which is guaranteed to be accepted with a simple insert, update or copy. For the PostGIS 'geometry' type these are:
>
> ```
> - Output
>   - binary: EWKB
>         ascii: HEXEWKB (EWKB in hex form)
> - Input
>   - binary: EWKB
>         ascii: HEXEWKB|EWKT
> ```
>
> For example this statement reads EWKT and returns HEXEWKB in the process of canonical ascii input/output:
>
> ```
> =# SELECT 'SRID=4;POINT(0 0)'::geometry;
>
> geometry
> ----------------------------------------------------
> 01010000200400000000000000000000000000000000000000
> (1 row)
> ```